# ¿cómo obtener un resultado en SQL de Respuestas correctas y tiempo en que se insertaron e incorrectas y también en tiempo que se insertaron?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
 SELECT nombre, puntos FROM juego1 WHERE numerodepregunta='1' 
 AND respuesta='correcta;
```

En este ejemplo solo me devuelve:

```
nombre  Puntos
nomb1.  1
nomb2.  1
nomb3.  1
nomb4.  1//etc.
```

En donde "nomb1." es el primero que ingreso en la tabla y así sucesivamente...
Y lo que quiero obtener es:

```
Nombre  Puntos
nomb1.  1
nomb2.  1
nomb3.  1
nomb4.  1
nomb5.  0
nomb6.  0
nomb7.  0
nomb8.  0//etc.
```

En este ejemplo también aparecen los usuarios que contestaron incorrectamente y también por tiempo en que ingresaron a la BD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo agregar un where in

SELECT nombre, puntos FROM juego1 WHERE numerodepregunta='$ndp' AND puntos in ('1','0') ORDER BY juego1.puntos DESC

Comment: Me ayudaste mucho, así quedo la consulta: SELECT nombre, puntos FROM juego1 WHERE `numerodepregunta`='$ndp' AND `puntos` in ('1','0') ORDER BY `juego1`.`puntos` DESC; ¿Puedes corregir tu respuesta para poner que solucionó mi problema por favor?

Comment: Ya quedo editado